# How do I get the parsed configuration object from another plugin in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

There's an open source Gradle plugin that I use (in this case, it happens to be [`wuff`](https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff)).  I have my own Gradle plugin, called `Foo`.

My `foo` plugin needs to peek into the configuration data for `wuff` - it depends on some values which are set there.

How do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does `wuff` set the values ? Is it in the `wuff` plugin object ?
You can get the `wuff` plugin reference as

```
if (project.plugins.hasPlugin('wuff')) {
    wuffPlugin = project.plugins.findPlugin('wuff')
    //access the config from wuffPlugin object.
}
```